# Take column value on button click

Tags: c#, asp.net, aspxgridview

I have table with several rows. In front of every row there's a "Select" button.
Table :

https://jsfiddle.net/qmg1309n/2/

Table is populated with procedure that takes the values from the database.
C# part where I take values and send the to aspx:

```
LogicTableAdapters.getLevelTableAdapter getLvl = new LogicTableAdapters.getLevelTableAdapter();

DataTable dtLvl = getLvl.getLevel(Convert.ToInt32(ddlLevel.SelectedValue));

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[4]{ new DataColumn("ObjtID", typeof(int)), new DataColumn("Name", typeof(string)), new DataColumn("BCC", typeof(string)),new DataColumn("ParentName", typeof(string))  ,});
foreach (DataRow dr in dtLvl.Rows)
{
    dt.Rows.Add(Convert.ToInt32(dr["ObjID"]), dr["Name"].ToString(), dr["BCC"].ToString(), dr["ParentName"].ToString());
}

gvObject.DataSource = dt;
gvObject.DataBind();
```

This is the asp part:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvObject" runat="server" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CssClass="GridView">

    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <button class="myBtn" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" style="vertical-align: middle"><span>Select</span></button>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ObjID">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="ObjID" runat="server" class="ObjekatID" Width="118px" Height="36px" Style="text-align: center" Font-Names="Georgia" margin-Left="100px" Text='<%# Bind("ObjID") %>'></asp:Label>


            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
            <ItemTemplate>

                <asp:Label ID="Name" runat="server" Width="118px" Height="26px" Style="text-align: center" Font-Names="Georgia" margin-Left="100px" Text='<%# Bind("Name") %>'></asp:Label>

            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="BCC">
            <ItemTemplate>

                <asp:Label ID="BCC" runat="server" Width="118px" Height="26px" Style="text-align: center" Font-Names="Georgia" margin-Left="100px" Text='<%# Bind("BCC") %>'></asp:Label>

            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ParentName">
            <ItemTemplate>

                <asp:Label ID="ParentName" runat="server" Width="118px" Height="26px" Style="text-align: center" Font-Names="Georgia" margin-Left="100px" Text='<%# Bind("ParentName") %>'></asp:Label>

            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>

</asp:GridView>
```

When the button is "select" is clicked in front of every row I need to take ObjID value just for that row and store it in the variable in C#.

That ObjID value will later be paramether for new GET procedure that generates new table when the select button is clicked.

Can someone help me with this ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I made a mistake. I took the value with jquery and pick it up in web method and stored it in the variable. The trouble is that I need to take that value before the page is loaded :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have defined the `OnSelectedIndexChanged` event in the GridView, you can use that to find the Label of the SelectedRow.

```
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label lbl = ((GridView)sender).SelectedRow.FindControl("ObjID") as Label;

    var ObjID = lbl.Text;
}
```

aspx

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateSelectButton="true" 
    OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged">
```

UPDTATE

If you want it only in front-end, you can do this. Add a data property to the button.

```
<button class="myBtn" type="button" data-objid="<%# Eval("ObjID") %>">
```

Then when the button is clicked you can read that property and get the value.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.myBtn').click(function () {
        alert($(this).data('objid'));
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for you response ! https://jsfiddle.net/ts0Lmdqf/4/
But now every column is duplicated and I have another select buttom.
I need class="myBtn" select button to be clicked because that opens a bootstrap modal with a new table that take ObjID as a paramether for get procedure.
Can you plase help ?

Comment: Updated my answer. If you do not need the value in code behind you can forget the first part of my answer.